# How to use simulation time to triger action in modules?

Tags: simulation, omnet++

I want to create simulation with server and 2 nodes. Nodes have defined vector that contain times for turn on/off.(example timersOnOff = 5,10,13,25 … nod will turn on in 5th second of beginning simulation, and then will be shutdown in 10th seconds etc). How to trigger action at certain time to send msg to node to "turn on" or "turn off".?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that these times are written in `timersOnOff` declared as:

```
std::vector<simtime_t> timersOnOff;
```

In `initialize()` add the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < timersOnOff.size(); i = i + 2) {
   simtime_t timeOn = timersOnOff[i];
   simtime_t timeOff = timersOnOff[i+1];
   cMessage * msgOn = new cMessage("nodeOn");     // (1)
   cMessage * msgOff = new cMessage("nodeOff");   // (2)
   scheduleAt (timeOn, msgOn);
   scheduleAt (timeOff, msgOff);
}
```

The above code schedules all ON and OFF events.

Then, in `handleMessage()` add:

```
if (msg->isSelfMessage()) {
   if (msg->isName("nodeOn")) {  // the same name as in (1)
      delete msg;
      // turning on the node

   } else if (msg->isName("nodeOff")) { // the same name as in (2)
      delete msg;
      // turning off the node

   }
} else {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: During initialization we are using scheduleAt to insert msg inside FES and there is only one(global) for whole simulation, correct?. And msg from all module are sequently allign inside FES, and the simulation execution starts until FES is empty. I am newbee and I am trying to understand how omnet execute simulation.

Comment: In some example I have found that initialization() phase is used for creating vector, and then activity() is used for scheduling of messages (multi level initialization is used). Is this how it should be done and what is differece between those two approaches?